# Image not rendering on blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have been trying to render my scene but its stuck in a blank space and its at 0%.

[image]

Here are  my setting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your blend file friend if its possible.

Comment: Why are you using Experimental Set on the Feature Set in your second image? Have you tried to change it to another setting? Maybe that's why you got blank renders.